# HTTPServer send get request from server to client

Tags: java, http

I want to send parameters (GET request) from the http server to the client.

```
    private void displayPage(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
    String root = "html";
    URI uri = he.getRequestURI();
    File file = new File(root + uri.getPath()).getCanonicalFile();
    OutputStream os = null;
    String response = "";

    if (!file.isFile()) {
        // Object does not exist or is not a file: reject with 404 error.
        response = "404 (Not Found)\n";
        he.sendResponseHeaders(404, response.length());
        os = he.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes());

    } else {
        // Object exists and is a file: accept with response code 200.
        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
        os = he.getResponseBody();
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = fs.read(buffer)) >= 0) 
            os.write(buffer,0,count);  
        fs.close();
    }
    os.close();
}
```

This method send request .html page to the client.

I would like to insert this parameters in the http header:

```
String urlParameters = "sensornumber="+N_SENSORI+"&lightnumber="+N_LUCI+"&defaultlightname="+LUCE+"&defaultsensornumber="+SENSORE;
```

So I can use them in the javascript present in the .html file

Comment: why not generate html as required instead of sending static html with headers etc?

Comment: I won't endorse the logical thinking behind all this but to come to your question, what you should understand is that you are reading a file and then streaming it out. You should start looking at how to edit a file in java. That logic will go in your while loop with obvious if statements. That should solve the current issue.